# How to get sum of colums in a array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, calculated-columns

I was trying to make it and almost got it, but when I'm suming, it's summing  every column together. I mean first colums is ok, but next ones add the previous colums to total. I want them separelty, like each one independent. Help)))

```
    int[,] vektor;
        vektor = new int[2, 5];

        vektor[0, 0] = 8;
        vektor[0, 1] = 9;
        vektor[0, 2] = 1;
        vektor[0, 3] = 5;
        vektor[0, 4] = 6;
        vektor[1, 0] = 5;
        vektor[1, 1] = 3;
        vektor[1, 2] = 2;
        vektor[1, 3] = 11;
        vektor[1, 4] = 10;
        int row;
        int col;
        int totrow = 0;
        int totcol = 0;
        double media = 0.00;
        int j = 0;
        for (row = 0; row < vektor.GetLength(0); row++)
        {

            for (col = 0; col < vektor.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                Console.Write(vektor[row, col] + "\t");
                totrow += vektor[row, col];

            }

            Console.WriteLine(totrow);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (col = 0; col < vektor.GetLength(1); col++)
        {

            for (row = 0; row < vektor.GetLength(0); row++)
            {

                totcol += vektor[row, col];

            }

            Console.Write(totcol + "\t");

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `totcol` should be a list as well if you need separate column sums

Comment: What is the exact result you're looking for as output? I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What you are trying to do is get the number of columns in each row separately?

Comment: I was trying to sum the columns. I got it, I just had to resest the totcol to 0. Thank you anyway for your interest

Comment: if one answer helped you, accept it as such

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output to Console, what you're doing is fine except you're not resetting the sums for each column:

```
for (col = 0; col < vektor.GetLength(1); col++)
{
    totcol = 0; // <--- reset the sum to 0.

    for (row = 0; row < vektor.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        totcol += vektor[row, col];
    }
    Console.Write(totcol + "\t");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array will be fixed size (same column number for each row) then you can simply use

```
vektor.GetLength(1)/vektor.GetLength(0)
```

This division will give you the number of columns in each row. If what you have is different number of columns in each row use an array to store the number of columns instead of a total counter. Everytime you change row change the position in the array.

```
int totcol[vektor.GetLength(0)];

       for (row= 0; col < vektor.GetLength(0); col++)
        {

            for (col= 0; row < vektor.GetLength(1); row++)
            {

                totcol[row= += vektor[row, col];

            }
```

Also totcol needs to be zeroed for calculations to be correct.

If on the other hand you need to simply print the number of columns in each row you do not need an array but simply zeroing `totcol` after each column counting iteration. Like so:

```
       for (row= 0; col < vektor.GetLength(0); col++)
        {
              totcol=0;
            for (col= 0; row < vektor.GetLength(1); row++)
            {

               Console.WriteLine(totcol);

            }
```